# Scrolling on UITableView shows bottom part of table cut off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a TableView in a View, and when it scrolls, the rounded part of the table at the bottom is cut off. I'd like it to behave like the Stocks app, where the table view is fixed with round corners and scrolling scrolls within the fixed rounded corners. How is that done?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add the QuartzCore framework library to your project if you haven't.

Then, in your UIViewController that manages the UITableView, do:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And then on viewDidLoad:

```
myTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

And that will give it 8px rounded corners. The QuartzCore framework exposes a lot of very useful things that you can do with UIViews and their internal layers. Experiment away!

Comment: Tried that and its still not working :( looks exactly teh same

Comment: Could you try posting a full screenshot, because that little sliver makes it difficult to understand what it is exactly that you are doing wrong.

Comment: I have an outerview that contains a tableview and a label below the tableview. The tableview is sized to be 3/4 of the screen. The elements in the table view exceed the scroll space, so when I scroll you see it being cut off without the rounded corner. the "oad" you see is the end of the label that should show below the table view. Does that help?

Comment: In that case, you might want to look at CAShapeLayer and masking. What you are asking is actually fairly complicated. [This](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/95917-adding-rounded-corners-only-top-uitableview.html) should give you a nice pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For your This Requirement i just tell you use ScrollView Help ...
In ScrollView Just Put tableview and in viewWillAppear or where your data reload at that time put bellow code

```
     yourTableView.frame = CGRectMake(yourTableView.frame.origin.x,yourTableView.frame.origin.y, yourTableView.frame.size.width, yourTableView.contentSize.height);

    float ftbl = yourTableView.frame.origin.y + yourTableView.contentSize.height + 15;
    yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, ftbl);
```

Here declare tableview type with Grouped if required..
Sure this useful to you ...
:)